# Is it possible to use the caret package in R with non-numerical data? 

Tags: r, caret

I was wondering if it is possible to use the caret package with non numerical data.
I know, for example, if I want to use a simple linear regression `lm` I could have a factor variable for classification.
However, caret blows up if I attempt this. I'm also following the step outlined here [The caret Package: A Unifed Interface for Predictive
Models](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2010/slides/Kuhn.pdf)

for illustration I'm attempting to run `stepDurationlm <- train (x= trainDescr, y=trainClass, method="lm")`

on

```
str(trainDescr)
'data.frame':   589235 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Anon.Student.Id    : Factor w/ 574 levels "02i5jCrfQK","02ZjVTxC34",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Step.Duration..sec.: num  5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 4 4 ...
```

I get

```
Error in train.default(x = trainDescr, y = trainClass, method = "lm") : 
All predictors must be numeric for this model. Use the formula interface: train(formula, data)
```

alternatively, could anyone explain how to have a test set for model performance in R? That's what's motivating me to get caret working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post a reproducible example.  You should also be more specific: in this case by "non-numeric data" you mean "factor data."

If you wish to use `lm` with categorical variables, you have 2 options: create the dummy matrix yourself, or use caret's formula interface.  Here's an example of option 2:

```
train(y~., data=data.frame(x=trainDescr,y=trainClass), method = "lm")
```

Where . covers all variables in x

Answer (score 1):

As laid out [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper):

> The train function has the following arguments: x: a matrix or data frame of predictors. Currently, the function only accepts numeric
>   values (i.e., no factors or character variables). In some cases, the
>   model.matrix function may be needed to generate a data frame or matrix
>   of purely numeric data

Although maybe this has changed by now.